# How to pass parameters in Perl with out data getting altered

Tags: xml, perl, parameters, subroutine

I have curious problem I can't get around. Can you please see what I am doing wrong. I am trying to build an XML in Perl using XML::LibXML. All works fine until I start building sub routine and pass arguments.

First The code that works

```
 my $root = $doc->createElement("XML_FILE");
 my @sortedOuterTags = qw ( JMS_VERSION
                       FILE_NAME
                       SUBMIT_BY
                       SUBMIT_DATE
                      );

# Use hash slice to access the list in hash elements
# Remember has elements are accessed randomly, hence hash slice-ing

 my %outHashTags;
 @outHashTags { @sortedOuterTags } = ( 'data1',
                                'data2',
                                'data3',
                                'data3');

for my $name (@sortedOuterTags) {
    my $outTag = $doc->createElement($name);
    my $outValue = $outHashTags{$name};
    $outTag->appendTextNode($outValue);
    $root->appendChild($outTag);
}
```

Builds output:

```
<JMS_VERSION>data1</JMS_VERSION>

<FILE_NAME>data2</FILE_NAME>

<SUBMIT_BY>data3</SUBMIT_BY>

<SUBMIT_DATE>data4</SUBMIT_DATE>
```

Now the error:

As soon as I spin off for loop to an sub routine as show below I get errors. I am passing 3 paramenters.
1) can't get array values of storedReportTag
2) can't get %reportHashTag data
3) $report element is empty

Code:

```
buildXMLElements(\@sortedReportTag, %reportHashTags, $report);

sub buildXMLElements() {
    my( @elementTags, %hashTags, $parentElement) = @_;

    for my $name (@elementTags) {
        my $reportTag = $doc->createElement($name);
        my $reportValue = $hashTags{$name};
        $reportTag->appendTextNode($reportValue);
        $parentElement->appendChild($reportTag);
    }
}
```

I want to put in sub as I have several tags to build to re-use the code. I tried passing parameters both directly and as reference.......

Thank you

Update:

After editing my Sub it now looks like this:

```
buildXMLElements(\@sortedReportTag, \%reportHashTags, $report);

sub buildXMLElements() {
    my($elementTags, $hashTags, $parentElement) = @_;
    for my $name (@$elementTags) {
        my $reportTag = $doc->createElement($name);
        my $reportValue = $hashTags->[$name];
        $reportTag->appendTextNode($reportValue);
        $parentElement->appendChild($reportTag);
    }
}
```

it dies at the line:

```
my $reportValue = $hashTags->[$name];
```

Final update:

With Jim's help I corrected the code: Here is final version that works

```
buildXMLElements(\@sortedReportTag, \%reportHashTags, $report);

sub buildXMLElements() {
    my($elementTags, $hashTags, $parentElement) = @_;
        for my $name (@$elementTags) {
        my $reportTag = $doc->createElement($name);
        my $reportValue = $hashTags->{$name};
        $reportTag->appendTextNode($reportValue);
        $parentElement->appendChild($reportTag);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354417

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161043

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
buildXMLElements(\@sortedReportTag, %reportHashTags, $report);
...
sub buildXMLElements() {
  my( @elementTags, %hashTags, $parentElement) = @_;
```

You can't do that.  The entire contents of `@_` will be assigned to `@elementTags`.  To pass arrays or hashes to a subroutine you must pass a reference.  Try instead

```
buildXMLElements(\@sortedReportTag, \%reportHashTags, $report);
...
sub buildXMLElements() {
  my( $elementTags, $hashTags, $parentElement) = @_;
```

Now, in the subroutine `$elementTags` is an array reference, and `$hashTags` is a hash reference. To refer to an element of `elementTags` use `$elementTags->[$i]` or to refer to the entire array do `@$elementTags`.
Likewise, for `reportHashTags` key lookup use `$hashTags->[$key]`, or for the entire hash use `%$hashTags`.

Comment: Well when I reference the hash it throws me an error. Here is the code for it. I am new to perl       sub buildXMLElements() {
 my($elementTags, $hashTags, $parentElement) = @_;
    for my $name (@$elementTags) {
    my $reportTag = $doc->createElement($name);
    my $reportValue = $hashTags->[$name];
    $reportTag->appendTextNode($reportValue);
    $parentElement->appendChild($reportTag);
}
} it dies at the line my $reportValue = $hashTags->[$name]; :(

Comment: Don't put code in a comment.  Either edit your original post or ask a new question with the updated code.  That said, the code `$reportValue = $hashTags->[$name];` is invalid because you used brackets `[]` instead of braces `{}` for a hash.